# Returning null and other values. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Just started to fiddle in SQL and really dont have any experience with coding before but it's fun.
Here is the issue im having.

```
WHERE ([Text 7] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like '%perm%' 
   OR Article.Stat2 IN ('70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '83'))
      AND NOT Articletype ='z'
```

In the column Articletype there is multiple values, z,q,s,/ and  NULL.
If I remove z it doesnt return the NULL values any longer

How do i get it to return NULL values and the others but not z without it conflicting my orignal selection of articles.

Comment: `AND (Articletype <> 'z' OR Articletype IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` does not equal anything, but conversely it does not `NOT` equal anything either. `NULL` is an *unknown* value. The only way you can compare to a `NULL` value is with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

With an expression like `YourColumn = 'z'` if `YourColumn` has the value `NULL` then the result of that expression is **not** `False`, it's `Unknown`. For the purposes of the `WHERE` here it doesn't "matter", as `Unknown` isn't `True`, and so the row it filtered out.

For `NOT(YourColumn = 'z')`, however, this evaluates to `NOT(Unknown)` which is **also** `Unknown`; which is (importantly) *not* `True`.

Therefore, if you are checking for `NULL` values, you need to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

In this case that would be the below:

```sql
WHERE ([Text 7] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like '%perm%' OR Article.Stat2 IN ('70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '83'))
  AND (Articletype != 'z' OR Articletype IS NULL)
```

---

Couple of extra notes:
Do you *really* need the `COLLATE` here? This will cause the query to be non_SARGable. What is the `COLLATE` achieving here, to change it to a non case-sensitive collation? If so, you might be better off with an indexed `PERSISTED` computed column.

Also, don't provide numbers in single quotes; they don't need them. Your `IN` should be `Stat2 IN (70,71,...,83)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and also the solution,

Yes you are correct about why im using `COLLATE`.
I'll look into the suggestion of indexed `PERSISTED` computed column.

Comment: If it solves the problem, @IrLurker , then please do mark it as the solution. This lets future readers know the answer was helpful, and other users know the question has been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the check as follows:

```
AND (Articletype IS NULL OR Articletype <> 'z')
```

PS I switched to using `<>` because I believe that is more readable than `NOT ... =`.